# Asynchronous methods in using statement

Tags: c#, asynchronous, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5, using

Note: I'm using C# in Unity, that means version .NET **3.5**, so I cannot use `await` or `async` keyword..

What will happen to **using statement** when I put a method in it which works **asynchronously**?

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(urlUri, outputFile);
}
SomeMethod1();
SomeMethod2();
```

As you know, after the method `DownloadFileAsync()` is called, `SomeMethod1()` will be called which is out of the `using` block while `DownloadFileAsync()` is still **working**. So now I'm really confused what would happen to the using statement and the asynchronous method in this case.

Would `Dispose()` of `wc` be called at the right time without any problems?

If not, how do I correct this example?

Comment: This will not work.  Use `await` with `*TaskAsync`

Comment: @JasonEvans, why do you say yes? since OP is not using `await`, then there is a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies, I made this stupid mistakes several times.. Then how do I avoid this? Just add await keyword?

Comment: Since the OP isn't using an async method that returns a `Task`, the Mjolnir'ed duplicate is less than useful. The OP of the duplicate was fortuitous in that they didn't know they just needed to use async/await with their method. To @JenixGuy, if you're able to use `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()` you can use what's proposed in the duplicate.

Comment: `Just add await keyword` if you knew what await did the answer would be obvious to you. Don't add keywords to your code when you are not sure what they do.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the comments:

> Then how do I avoid this? Just add await keyword?

No, you can't *just* do that. (And that's why the previously proposed duplicate question was not in fact a duplicate…your scenario is subtly different.) You will need to delay the dispose until the download has completed, but this is complicated by your need to execute two more program statements (at least…it's impossible to know for sure without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

I *do* think you should switch to the awaitable [`WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193917(v=vs.110).aspx) method, as this will at least simplify the implementation, making it simple to retain the `using` statement.

You can address the other part of the problem by capturing the returned `Task` object and not awaiting it until *after* your other program statements have executed:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    Task task = wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(urlUri, outputFile);
    SomeMethod1();
    SomeMethod2();
    await task;
}
```

In this way, the download can be started, your other two methods called, and *then* the code will wait for the completion of the download. Only when it's completed will the `using` block then be exited, allowing the `WebClient` object to be disposed.

Of course, in your current implementation you undoubtedly are handling an appropriate `DownloadXXXCompleted` event. If you want, you can continue using the object that way. But IMHO once you have switched over to using `await`, it's much better to just put after the `await` the code that needs to execute on the completion of the operation. This keeps all of the code relevant to the operation in one place and simplifies the implementation.

If for some reason you can't use `await`, then you will have to use some alternate mechanism for delaying the dispose of the `WebClient`. Some approaches will allow you to continue to use `using`, others will require that you call `Dispose()` in the `DownloadXXXCompleted` event handler. Without a more complete code example, and a clear explanation for why `await` is not suitable, it would not be possible to say for sure what the best alternative would be.

**EDIT:**

Since you've confirmed that you don't have access to `await` in the current code, here are a couple of other options compatible with older code…

One possibility is to just wait in the same thread after starting the operation:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) {
    object waitObject = new object();
    lock (waitObject)
    {
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            lock (waitObject) Monitor.Pulse(waitObject);
        };
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(urlUri, outputFile);
        SomeMethod1();
        SomeMethod2();
        Monitor.Wait(waitObject);
    }
}
```

*(Note: one can use any suitable synchronization above, such as `ManualResetEvent`, `CountdownEvent`, or even `Semaphore` and/or "slim" equivalents. I use `Monitor` simply due to its simplicity and efficiency, and take as granted readers can adjust to accommodate their preferred means of synchronization. One obvious reason one might prefer something *other* than `Monitor` is that the other types of synchronization techniques won't run the risk of having the `DownloadFileCompleted` event handler itself block waiting on the `SomeMethod1()` and `SomeMethod2()` methods to complete. Whether this is important depends of course on how long those method calls would take as compared to the file download.)*

The above will, however, block the current thread. In some cases this may be fine, but most often the operation is being initiated in the UI thread, and that thread should not be blocked for the duration of the operation. In that case, you will want to forego `using` altogether and just call `Dispose()` from the completion event handler:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    wc.Dispose();
};
wc.DownloadFileAsync(urlUri, outputFile);
SomeMethod1();
SomeMethod2();
```

Comment: I just found out the keyword await can't be used in version 3.5 Unity3D is using.. But, your answer is very helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Very good. Especially the last one is very easy and clean! :)

Answer (score 6):

The `System.Net.WebClient` provides the event `DownloadFileCompleted`.  You could add a handler for that event and dispose of the client at that time.

Comment: Yep! This is the one of the best ways I can choose, thanks!