# Why is Dispose called before its finishes async task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've recently stumbled on this strange error. It looks like one of my object is disposing before my method finish all async Task. But let's take a look.

I have that async method which seeds my database. It's called in `Startup` class in `Configure` method.

```cs
private void InitDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app) {
            using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope()) {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<GrabGoContext>();
                    new DatabaseInitializer().InitializeAsync(context,
                        services.GetService(typeof(UserManager<User>)) as UserManager<User>,
                        services.GetService(typeof(SignInManager<User>)) as SignInManager<User>,
                        services.GetService(typeof(RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>)) as RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>>,
                        _logger).Wait();
                    _logger.LogDebug("Database initialization finished.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
                    if (Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Break();
                }
            }
        }
```

And that method from `DatabaseInitializer` class:

```cs
    public async Task InitializeAsync(GrabGoContext context,
        UserManager<User> userManager,
        SignInManager<User> signInManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> roleManager,
        ILogger<Startup> logger) {

        if(IsDatabaseInialized) return;
        IsDatabaseInialized = true;
        await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        await AddStores(context);
        await AddProducts(context);
        await AddRoles(roleManager)
            .ContinueWith(t => AddRolesToUsers(userManager)); // <- Here throws exception "System.ObjectDisposedException" for object `userManager`
        await AddUsers(userManager);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

The thing is that if I use `ContinueWith` to chain Tasks, it throws `System.ObjectDisposedException` on `userManager` object. But I need to use `ContinueWith`, because I need `Roles` before I will assign users to that roles.

My methods responsible for adding roles

```cs
        private async Task AddRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> roleManager) {
            if (await roleManager.Roles.AnyAsync()) return;

            var roles = (List<IdentityRole<int>>) new RolesListExample().GetExamples();
            foreach (var role in roles) {
                var result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                if(!result.Succeeded) throw new ApplicationException("Erros while adding roles: " +
                                                                     JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Errors));
            }
        }

        private async Task AddRolesToUsers(UserManager<User> userManager) {
            var registerModels = (List<RegisterModel>)new RegisterListRequestExample().GetExamples();
            foreach(var registerModel in registerModels) {
                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(registerModel.Email);
                var result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, registerModel.Role.ToString());
                if(!result.Succeeded)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Erros while adding roles to user: " +
                                                   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Errors));
            }
        }
```

And also my `RolesListExample` class :

```
    public class RolesListExample : IExamplesProvider {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public object GetExamples() {
            var roles = new List<IdentityRole<int>>();
            foreach (var availableRole in (AvailableRoles[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(AvailableRoles))) {
                roles.Add(new IdentityRole<int>(availableRole.ToString()));
            }
            return roles;
        }
    }
```

My question is:

> Why is my object disposing before all Tasks are finished?

I assume that's because of the `using`. 
Also I found that [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722968/asynchronous-methods-in-using-statement), but didn't clarify situation for me.

@Update

As suggested by @PanagiotisKanavos I removed `using` statement and it solved my disposing problem. Thanks!

Comment: You should start by simplifying your code and actually using dependency injection, instead of trying to grab service instances. The way this code is written it's little better than using `new GrabGoContext()`, `new UserManager()` etc.You don't need a scope as none of those classes is going to be used outside the method.

Comment: If you need to use those services in `DatabaseInitializer`, add them as constructor dependencies of `DatabaseInitializer` itself and create the class through DI. `InitDatabase` doesn't need to know how DatabaseInitializer is implemented, like it does now

Comment: As for chaining tasks, that's what `await` does. Why not use `await AddRoles(); await AddRolesToUsers();` ? Why use `ContinueWith()` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Anyway if I use it like this I got error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Role CLIENT does not exist.'" in `AddRoleToUsers()`.

Comment: Than the problem is solved, right? @Morasiu

Comment: @Morasiu this means you have more bugs  in those methods that you haven't posted. Why didn't `AddRoles` add that role when it claims it had? `ContinueWith` just moved the bug to the next call and resulted in that `ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: @PatrickHofman Still checking.

Comment: @Morasiu it's not possible to guess what's wrong without the code. It has nothing to do with `async` or Tasks anyway. For all one knows, one of those methods may be calling `Dispose()` on one of the contexts explicitly, or wrapping it in a `using` block. Or there could be a `catch{}` that hides errors

Comment: Nevermind. Cleaning table and removed using solved it. Thanks for help. I really appreciate it.